# Change a custom MKAnnotationView when it is selected

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have a MKMapView with several different types of `MKAnnotationView`s on it. Chiefly, I have a `PricedAnnotationView`, which is a fairly complicated `MKAnnotationView` with a `UILabel` and some other views. The label can have different text in it, based off of the original `MKAnnotation` that it is associated with.

```
class PricedAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {

    static let ReuseID = "pricedAnnotation"

    let labelContainingView: UIView = {
        let containingView = UIView()
        containingView.backgroundColor = .blue
        containingView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        containingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return containingView
    }()

    let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
        label.textColor = .white
        label.font = ViewConstants.Text.BodyFontBold
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let containingView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView(frame:CGRect.zero)
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

        let triangle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 9, height: 9))
        triangle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 5.5, y: 11))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 11, y: 0))
        path.close()
        let triangleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        triangleLayer.path = path.cgPath
        triangleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        triangle.layer.addSublayer(triangleLayer)

        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.canShowCallout = false
        self.frame = labelContainingView.frame

        labelContainingView.addSubview(label)
        containingView.addSubview(labelContainingView)
        containingView.addSubview(triangle)
        self.addSubview(containingView)

        // Get the label correctly inset in the labelContainingView
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelContainingView.topAnchor, constant: 3).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelContainingView.leadingAnchor, constant: 6).isActive = true
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelContainingView.trailingAnchor, constant: -6).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelContainingView.bottomAnchor, constant: -3).isActive = true

        // The triangle.topAnchor purposefully puts the triangle a bit under the label. In testing, while moving around
        // the map, a little gap would appear between the label and the triangle. This change fixes that. The triangle
        // was made two pixels bigger so that it would appear to be the same size.
        triangle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelContainingView.bottomAnchor, constant: -2).isActive = true
        triangle.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelContainingView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        triangle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 11).isActive = true
        triangle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 11).isActive = true

        containingView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelContainingView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        containingView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelContainingView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        containingView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelContainingView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        containingView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: triangle.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    }

    /// - Tag: DisplayConfiguration
    override func prepareForDisplay() {

        super.prepareForDisplay()
        displayPriority = .required

        guard let annotation = annotation as? MyAnnotation else { return }
        if case let .priced(price, currencyCode) = annotation.status {
            label.text = StringFormatter.formatCurrency(amount: price, currencyCode: currencyCode)
        }
        self.layoutIfNeeded()   // Calculate the size from the constraints so we can know the frame.
        self.frame = containingView.frame
        self.centerOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -(containingView.frame.height / 2))    // Center point should be where the triangle points
    }
}
```

Every other annotation is much simpler and just uses one of two `UIImage` to support itself. I use two different reuse Ids with those simpler `MKAnnotationView` so I don't have to keep setting the image; I don't know if that is a best practice or not. Here is a sample of how I do it:

```
private let unpricedAnnotationClusterId = "unpriced"
private let unpricedAnnotationReuseID = "unpricedAnnotation"

func createUnpricedAnnotation(mapView: MKMapView, annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView {
    let annotationView: MKAnnotationView
    if let dequeuedAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: unpricedAnnotationReuseID) {
        annotationView = dequeuedAnnotationView
        annotationView.annotation = annotation
    } else {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: unpricedAnnotationReuseID)
        annotationView.image = UIImage(bundleAsset: "map_pin_blue")
        annotationView.centerOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -(annotationView.frame.height / 2))    // Center point should be where the pin points
        annotationView.clusteringIdentifier = unpricedAnnotationClusterId
    }
    return annotationView
}
```

When the user taps on an annotation in the map, I have an information window below the map populate with information about the selected item. That works fine. I would like it if the annotation view changed though so it was clear as to where the item is that is being displayed. I would be okay with just setting it to an image. However, I can't find any example of how to do that; most examples just change the image. When I try that with `PricedAnnotationView` the previous label does not go away, although the two simpler annotations work fine. I'm also unsure how changing the image would affect the reuse Ids that I am using. I don't see a way to manually change the reuse identifier.

My `MKMapViewDelegate` has these functions:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if allowSelection {
        if let item : MyAnnotation = view.annotation as? MyAnnotation {
            ...
            // display selected item in information view
            ...
        }
        view.image = UIImage(bundleAsset: "map_pin_red")
    }
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    guard let annotation = annotation as? MyAnnotation else {
        return nil
    }

    switch annotation.status {
    case .notPriced:
        return createUnpricedAnnotation(mapView: mapView, annotation: annotation)
    case .priced(_, _):
        return PricedAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: PricedAnnotationView.ReuseID)
    default:
        return createErrorAnnotation(mapView: mapView, annotation: annotation)
    }
}
```

If I could go the route of just setting the image, how do I change it back after the user has selected something else. Would I need to recreate `PricedAnnotationView` from scratch if it was previously one of those annotation? What would that do to the reuse Ids and the reuse queue?

When I have just changed the image, the view for `PricedAnnotationView` does not actually go away, and is just moved to the side as the image is shown beneath.

[image]

Ideally, I could do something to trigger a call to `mapView(_:viewFor:)` and have some intelligence in there to remember if the item is selected or now, but I have not found anything in my research to show how to do that. (It is not completely trivial because the `isSelected` property does not seem to be set on the `MKAnnotationView` that I would have just dequeued. No surprise there.)

Any suggestions as to how to handle this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you show us your current code for what you do have, and maybe some screenshots of the behavior you're experiencing so that we could get a better idea of what you're dealing with?

Answer (score 1):

I've played around with this, and here is what I've done to get around this issue:

I stopped using different reuse ids for the two types of image annotations. I created this function to manage that:

```
func createImageAnnotation(mapView: MKMapView, annotation: MKAnnotation, imageString: String) -> MKAnnotationView {
    let annotationView: MKAnnotationView
    if let dequeuedAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: imageAnnotationReuseID) {
        annotationView = dequeuedAnnotationView
        annotationView.annotation = annotation
    } else {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: imageAnnotationReuseID)
    }
    annotationView.image = UIImage(bundleAsset: imageString)
    annotationView.centerOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -(annotationView.frame.height / 2))    // Center point should be where the pin points
    annotationView.clusteringIdentifier = imageAnnotationClusterId
    return annotationView
}
```

I then added to the select and deselect calls so that the `PricedAnnotationView` is hidden and the image set when appropriate. Like this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if allowSelection {
        if let item : MyAnnotation = view.annotation as? MyAnnotation {
            ...
            // display selected item in information view
            ...
            view.image = UIImage(bundleAsset: selectedAnnotationImage)
            if case .priced(_,_) = item.rateStatus {
                (view as! PricedAnnotationView).containingView.isHidden = true
            }
            view.centerOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -(view.frame.height / 2))    // Center point should be where the pin points
        }
    }
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    guard let annotation = view.annotation as? MyAnnotation else { return }
    switch annotation.rateStatus {
    case .notPriced:
        view.image = UIImage(bundleAsset: unpricedAnnotationImage)
    case .priced(_, _):
        view.image = nil
        if let myView = (view as? PricedAnnotationView) {
            myView.containingView.isHidden = false
            view.frame =  myView.containingView.frame
            view.centerOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -(myView.containingView.frame.height / 2))    // Center point should be where the triangle points
        }
    default:
        view.image = UIImage(bundleAsset: errorAnnotationImage)
    }
}
```

This seems to mostly work, with the only quirk being that when the `PricedAnnotationView` is changed to the image, the image briefly and visibly shrinks from the old frame size to the correct frame size. However, if I do not set the frame, then the `PricedAnnotationView` is oddly offset.